# Typescript, Webpack, angular: Uncaught TypeError: Object(…) is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, type-definition

I'm starting in typescript and angular and I have to create a typedefinition for a custom library. When I run the app, I see that the javascript of my external library is present in the resources and loaded (checked via the console), but when my typescript code called  I got this error : `ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`. It seems that I'm missing something, my index.d.ts is in the same folder as my index.js,

*app.component.html*

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
<input value="open editor" type="button" (click)="openEditor()"/>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {createEditor, Editor} from "editor";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  openEditor() {
        console.log(new Editor());
        console.log(createEditor());
  }
}
```

*package.json*

```
  "name": "editor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "editor",
  "main":"index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "private": false,
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://localhost:4873"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "editor"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.33.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "files": [ "index.js","index.d.ts"]
}
```

*index.js*

```js
Editor = function(){
    alert("hello");
};
createEditor = function(){
    alert("hi");
};
```

*index.d.ts*

```js
export function createEditor():void;
export class Editor {
    constructor();
}
```

I oversimplified my code, as I saw that the angular import in my component put correctly the js into the dom, but fail when it call the typescript code. So I have a strong feeling that I am missing an important point in my typedefinition. It's probably something dumb that I failed to see (as I said, I'm new to typescript, angular)

any idea is welcome,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to move `import {createEditor, Editor} from "editor"; ` to the very beginning of the `.ts` file. It should not be in a function.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, 
I moved the import on the first line, sadly it didn't change anything.
Also tried to use the editor object only `console.log(new Editor())` but it failling the same way, with a different error for the object : WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Editor is not a constructor

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue

Comment: Second answer to the first comment, @HarunYılmaz I fixed the wrong copy paste, my import was no in the function in my code

Comment: Did you import your `index.js` file in the `scripts` section `angular.json` file?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz, yes I also tried that, but without success. Even before that change, I can access the function and the related object in the chrome debugger, It really seems that the link between the .d.ts file and the .js file is not done.

Comment: @Maryannah I can add the complete code of the angular component, also I use a local npm repository to deploy the component, but the deployed module only contains those 2 files (+package.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution,
It seems that the problem was in the js file,
the js file was missing the export declarations :

```js
module.exports = {createEditor,Editor};
```

So when webpack was trying to load the related import it was not loading it correctly.